# How determine request number on nginx per timeout when origin server is down?

Tags: linux, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I faced a problem case on linux nginx proxy server. I want to create a cache proxy server when original server is down. I determined proxy timeout 5s, but the main page loading have approximately 132 request. The proxy server is sending average 6 request per timeout period and waiting answers, so the page opens 132/6*5 second from cache. I tried with request zone, but i guess it represents the requests to nginx proxy cache server.
Are there any parameters to satisfy this request?

default.conf:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=90g inactive=10d;
server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name blabla.com;

  location / {
        #limit_req zone=mylimit;
        #limit_req_dry_run on;
        proxy_cache my_cache;
        proxy_cache_methods POST GET HEAD;
        proxy_connect_timeout 5s;
        proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri|$request_body";
        proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_cache_background_update   on;
        proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Set-Cookie Cache-Control;
        proxy_set_header     Host          $host;
        proxy_pass blabla.com;
        proxy_buffering on;
        proxy_cache_valid       200 304 301 10m; 
        proxy_cache_lock        on;
}}
```

nginx.conf:

````
user  nginx;
worker_processes  4;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  100;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:10m rate=150r/s;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}```
````